# Apple Mach-O Linker Error while running the Google Analytics project using Pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, cocoapods, xcode-workspace

I am a beginner level programmer and stuck in a problem with Google Analytics libraries while using cocoa pods.

I have installed the cocoa pods properly, installed the pod file 
with the dependencies inside it. Even I can see the Generated files inside the finder in a separate folder "`Pods`" also `GoogleAnalytics1.xcworkspace` but FYI

1. GoogleAnalytics1 is the name of my project.
2. GoogleAnalytics1.xcworkspace(created during the pod file installation) and GoogleAnalytics.xcodeproject are in the same folder named "GoogleAnalytics1".

### Any kind of help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

```
Ld /Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAnalytics1-gklncgocdpccldgqeibewkakesqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleAnalytics1.app/GoogleAnalytics1 normal i386
cd /Users/rajesh/Documents/Mangesh/BBI/Project/US/NewTableView16/GoogleAnalytics1
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -     
L/Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAnalytics1-    gklncgocdpccldgqeibewkakesqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -    L/Users/rajesh/Documents/Mangesh/BBI/Project/US/NewTableView16/GoogleAnalytics1/Pods/Google/Libraries -
L/Users/rajesh/Documents/Mangesh/BBI/Project/US/NewTableView16/GoogleAnalytics1/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries -
L/Users/rajesh/Documents/Mangesh/BBI/Project/US/NewTableView16/GoogleAnalytics1/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries -
L/Users/rajesh/Documents/Mangesh/BBI/Project/US/NewTableView16/GoogleAnalytics1/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries -
L/Users/rajesh/Documents/Mangesh/BBI/Project/US/NewTableView16/GoogleAnalytics1/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries -
F/Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAnalytics1-gklncgocdpccldgqeibewkakesqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist   /Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAnalytics1-  
gklncgocdpccldgqeibewkakesqh/Build/Intermediates/GoogleAnalytics1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleAnalytics1.build/Objects-normal/i386/GoogleAnalytics1.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lGGLAnalytics -lGGLCore -lGSDK_Overload -lGTMSessionFetcher_core -lGTMSessionFetcher_full -lGTMStackTrace -lGTM_AddressBook -lGTM_DebugUtils -lGTM_GTMURLBuilder -lGTM_KVO -lGTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments -lGTM_NSScannerJSON -lGTM_NSStringHTML -lGTM_NSStringXML -lGTM_Regex -lGTM_RoundedRectPath -lGTM_StringEncoding -lGTM_SystemVersion -lGTM_UIFont+LineHeight -lGTM_core -lGTM_iPhone -lGoogleAnalytics -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AddressBook -framework CoreData -framework SystemConfiguration -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -lPods-GoogleAnalytics1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAnalytics1-gklncgocdpccldgqeibewkakesqh/Build/Intermediates/GoogleAnalytics1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleAnalytics1.build/Objects-normal/i386/GoogleAnalytics1_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleAnalytics1-gklncgocdpccldgqeibewkakesqh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleAnalytics1.app/GoogleAnalytics1

ld: library not found for -lPods-GoogleAnalytics1
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Search for Library Search Path options in Project Settings under Build Settings and see if the path mentioned over there is correct or not.

Comment: Which on are you using . xcodeproject or . xcworkspace ???

Comment: First of all , I created the project , i.e GoogleAnalytics1.xcodeproject and respected viewControllers, appDelegate, Stroyboard etc., then when i installed the pod file using pod install on the terminal , i got GoogleAnalytics1.xcworkspace generated automatically with a Pods folder containing the google analytics libraries

Comment: Make sure you are opening 'GoogleAnalytics1.xcworkspace' because after intallation of pods it's workspace file that will run your application (code).

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadAwais it just worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you need to open the .xcworkspace file to open the project once you have pods working on it.

Another issue that I have come across though - XCode 7 (currently still in Beta but will be out normally soon) also produces these problems with cocoapods.  So if you're trying to use Swift 2 right now, cocoapods is not working in projects, and you get similar errors to the ones you are seeing.  I have had to uninstall cocoapods on current Swift 2 projects because of this issue, and Im currently looking at other options - Carthage looking like the best option so far.  https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage